# Write a JavaScript console program to read the input file and convert the sentence into acronym

Tags: javascript

Input and Output Format:
Refer sample input and output for formatting specifications.
Input is a data (sentence separated by space)
Output displays the converted acronym. (Uppercases)
Note: Input should be read from input.txt
Input accepts special characters and numbers also.

Input 1:
Hyper text markup language

Output 1:
HTML

Input 2:
What is the time now ?

Output 1:
WITTN?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = "What is the time now ?"
const output = str.split(" ")
    .map(w => w[0].toUpperCase()).join("")
console.log(str, output)
```